# Nuget package compatibility for .net core and .net framework 4.6

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-framework-version

I have created a nuget package which supports both .net framework and .net core.
But one class in it has references only available for .net core. 
I dnt need that class to be available in .net framwork

Is there any attribute or way is available, which exclude that class while building package for .net framweork?

This is how I am targetting frameworks

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;netstandard2.0;net45;net46</TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: As an aside, do you definitely need to target net45 and net46 differently? Ditto netcoreapp2.0 and netstandard2.0? If you target net45, the package will work with net46 anyway - likewise if you target netstandard2.0, the package will work with netcoreapp2.0. You'd normally only need to target all of them if you want to use net46 or netcoreapp2.0-specific features.

Comment: It's probably worth removing the screenshot now, as it's no longer relevant.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the conditional compilation symbols that will be supplied automatically on a per-target basis. For example:

```
// Put this at the start of the file (if you want some of the file to still be built)
// or class (if you just want to exclude a single class). You could even
// exclude just a single method, or part of a method.
#if NETCOREAPP2_0 || NETSTANDARD2_0

public class NetFrameworkOnlyClass
{
}

// And this at the end
#endif
```

Or instead of *including*, you could *exclude* like this:

```
#if !NET45 && !NET46
```

See the [cross-platform library tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/libraries) for a list of conditional compilation symbols defined in each environment. (I think it would be nice to have version-neutral "`NETCORE`", "`NETSTANDARD`" and "`NETFULL`" symbols or similar, but I don't believe those exist. You could specify them in your project file if you wanted to.)

Comment: Daisy , after added your way, please see attached image in screenshot of my question. Still getting build error

Comment: @Diana: You've put it after the `using` directives, which means it will fail if those namespaces aren't available. Move it to right at the start of the file, assuming you don't want anything in the file for netstandard/netcore.

Comment: @Diana: Although the error messages suggest that maybe you just haven't got a dependency on the right package for configuration and configuration extensions. Do you have a package reference to `Microsoft.Configuration.Extensions`?

Comment: You need to add the conditional compilation symbols for using statement too. See the serilog's LogContext as an example: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/3cd376c8c75ed49ab307c50cd80beaa06cbaecb7/src/Serilog/Context/LogContext.cs

Comment: Daisy thanks. It worked. I marked your answer as a good solution :)

Comment: @FeiyuZhou: In fact I don't think that's the problem here - looking at the screenshot closely, I suspect Diana doesn't have the right package references for configuration. But it's certainly reasonable to move the preprocessor directive right to the start of the file.

Comment: @DaisyShipton, `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` is not for net45 and net46, it depends on netstand2.0

Comment: @FeiyuZhou: Aha - I interpreted the question the wrong way round. Will edit the conditions. That explains everything...